# Adding favicons with generic option

Tags: javascript, favicon

I'd like to add favicons to my site using favicon.ico.

however I want to load a generic icon if the site does not provide one.

How can I test for the presense of a favicon and if one is not present manipulate the DOM to point to a generic favicon on the server.

Comment: You don't need Javascript for this.  You can use a div with a background which is the default, then include the favicon as an image in side of the div.

Comment: @Conspicuous I don't know, having an `img` which a `src` attribute that could possibly 404 smells to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some JavaScript. Adapt to suit...

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0],
    favicon = new Image;

favicon.onerror = function() {
    img.src = 'http://some-other-url.com/favicon.ico';
}

favicon.src = 'http://example.com/favicon.ico';
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this link, wish I would have found this sooner.

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="src_to_generic()" />
```

at

[w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp)

Just call a function on the onerror that resets the src to a generic image.