# How do I validate favicons using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In a previous post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034333/adding-favicons-with-generic-option) I asked how to display favicons with a generic option for favicons that do not exist.

```
<img src="example.com/favicon.ico"; alt=""/>
```

This code was posted:

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0],
    favicon = new Image;

favicon.src = 'http://example.com/favicon.ico'

favicon.onerror = function() 
  {
  img.src = 'http://url-on-local-server.com/favicon.ico';
  }
```

However I do not understand the need for "new Image", why can't I just use the existing image like this?

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0],
img.src = 'http://example.com/favicon.ico'
img.onerror = function() 
  {
  img.src = 'http://url-on-local-server.com/favicon.ico';
  }
```

Comment: You can use it without the `new Image` , but this could result in a endless loop when the other image also is unavailable.

Comment: I'm going to keep the other one on a local server so it is always there.

Comment: Bad things happen, also on "local servers". What if some Adblocker or similar blocks the image?

Comment: How does new Image change this fact?  What is the difference between loading an image via html or programatically using new Image.  If the source image is not there why would the behavior be different? Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this link, wish I would have found this an hour ago

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="src_to_generic()" />
```

at

[w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp)

Just call a function on the onerror that resets the src to a generic image.